# Is it possible to gradually read data from sql with read_sql to dataframe and at the same time write to parquet using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parquet

I have a large dataset which is really big to handle as a dataframe. Besides, It takes a long time reading whole data from database every time. Once I tried to write my data to parquet format, and read the data with `read_parquet` which was very faster.

So my question is: Can I read the data from database in chunk `read_sql`, write it to parquet with pandas `to_parquet`, read another chunk (when I delete previous one to save RAM) and append it to the parquet file and so on?

Comment: Did you give it a try to find out? Please post your attempt and any issues you face. Consider saving chunk size parquet files and then appending with pyarrow library. See [Using pyarrow how do you append to parquet file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47113813/1422451)

Comment: @Parfait Yes, I've give it a try. But as it's not some problem with code, I didn't share mine. Will try append with pyarrow.

Comment: @masoud Any luck / yet?

Comment: @jtlz2 I'll share my solution with you

Comment: Perfect, yes please!

Answer (score 1):

We can try using pyarrow to write from database directly to parquet:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

chunk = 1_000_000
pqwriter = None

for i, df in enumerate(pd.read_sql(query, con=con, chunksize=chunk):
   table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
   if i == 0:
      pqwriter = pq.ParquetWriter('output.parquet', table.schema)
   pqwriter.write_table(table)
   print('One Chunk Written')
if pqwriter:
   pqwriter.close()
```

Comment: Brilliant, works for me! How would you partition the output table as you write it?

Comment: How are you declaring/defining `con`?

Comment: Did you copy this from here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47839247/1021819 If so you ought at least to acknowledge it! :-S

Comment: @jtlz2 I had read that post  ( and of course other ones) when I asked the question. But not copy from it. I did just wrote the code that worked for me in my project :)

Comment: @jtlz2 you can define a con object with respect to your own database. I've used cx_Oracle to connect to oracle db.