Dask set dtype to an array of integers
With Dask I try to create a column that has type list with integers. For example:
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

# Have an example Dask Dataframe
ddf = dd.from_pandas(pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David', 'Emma'],
    'age': [25, 30, 35, 40, 45]
}), npartitions=1)

# now create an array type column
ddf["alist"] = ddf.apply(
    lambda k: [1, 0, 0], axis=1, meta=("alist", "list<item: int64>")
)

This particular case fails because:

TypeError: data type 'list<item: int64>' not understood

Eventually I want to write to parquet:
ddf.to_parquet(
    "example",
    engine="pyarrow",
    compression="snappy",
    overwrite=True,
)

and if I specify the dtype incorrect it raises:
ValueError: Failed to convert partition to expected pyarrow schema:
    `ArrowInvalid('Could not convert [1, 2, 3] with type list: tried to convert to int64', 'Conversion failed for column alist with type object')`

Expected partition schema:
    id: int64
    name: large_string
    age: int64
    alist: int64
    __null_dask_index__: int64

Received partition schema:
    id: int64
    name: large_string
    age: int64
    alist: list<item: int64>
      child 0, item: int64
    __null_dask_index__: int64

This error *may* be resolved by passing in schema information for
the mismatched column(s) using the `schema` keyword in `to_parquet`.


As discussed here, you can also specify the PyArrow types upon writing:
ddf.to_parquet(
    "example",
    engine="pyarrow",
    compression="snappy",
    overwrite=True,
    schema={
    "alist": pa.list_(pa.int32()),
    }
)


This works in overwrite=True mode only. When I try to append an existing table: ValueError: Appended dtypes differ. {('id', dtype('int64')), ('age', 'int64'), ('__null_dask_index__', dtype('int64')), ('alist', 'object'), ('id', 'int64'), ('name', string[pyarrow]), ('name', 'string'), ('alist', string[pyarrow]), ('age', dtype('int64')), ('__null_dask_index__', 'int64')}

I see that this is another issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47113813/using-pyarrow-how-do-you-append-to-parquet-file so I accepted the answer

Having also had this issue of directly creating and define a list column within a dask dataframe and getting the same issue, I opted for an alternative approach which involving serializing the list into a json string for storage.
Here is my suggestion
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import json

pdf = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David', 'Emma'],
    'age': [25, 30, 35, 40, 45],
    'alist': [[1, 0, 0] for _ in range(5)]  
})

pdf['alist'] = pdf['alist'].apply(json.dumps)

ddf = dd.from_pandas(pdf, npartitions=1)

import pyarrow as pa
schema = pa.schema([
    ('id', pa.int64()),
    ('name', pa.string()),
    ('age', pa.int64()),
    ('alist', pa.string()), 
])

ddf.to_parquet(
    "example",
    engine="pyarrow",
    compression="snappy",
    overwrite=True,
    schema=schema
)

